# Requesting value of property of a null object

Tags: actionscript-3

I m currently converting my old game project which is in AS2 into AS3 by myself. And there was a problem. In the AS2 version of my game I used to check for a movieclip's sub movieclip's property and use it for some calculations, using

```
if (mc1.mc2.prop == undefined){
    //do something
}
```

and during somepoint of the game the mc1 or mc2 is removed.
but in AS3 this no longer works because I cannot access the prop after mc1 or mc2 is removed.

Anyhelp? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give a more concise answer without knowing how your game actually works, but this function will allow you to check if a hierarchical value exists on an object:

```
function hasProp(target:Object, prop:String):Boolean
{
    var tests:Array = prop.split('.');
    var test:* = target;

    for each(var p:String in tests)
    {
        if(test.hasOwnProperty(p))
        {
            test = test[p];
        }
        else return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Used like:

```
if( hasProp(mc1, "mc2.prop") )
{
    // Property exists.
}
```

Comment: if mc2 is null, will mc1.mc2.harOwnProperty("prop") throw error?

Comment: @TommyX An AND statement is aborted when any of the assertions on the left are `false`, so no.

Comment: Thanks. Also I want to use a function to do the check. Are there anyway to check if input is something like mc1.mc2.mc3...mcn.prop, and check using the && and hasOwnProperty and return false when the prop is undefined? regardless of how many mcs are in the hierarchy.

Comment: @TommyX Yes that is possible, I'll update my answer after lunch.